# Should I have flagged this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spam, vote-to-close

Earlier today, I came across [a question asking for recommendations for software for an automotive repair shop](https://superuser.com/q/1647398/304000). This question is clearly off-topic, and I voted to close it as "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers".

After re-reading the question, I noticed that the OP mentioned a particular software they used that "is a fabulous online web portal", and that the OP's username was the same as this software. It seems that this question is not only off-topic but also not asked in good faith. Is it worth flagging it as spam in addition to close-voting it?

Comment: Don't vote to close spam. Only spam flag it. 6 spam flags and it's automatically deleted.

Comment: You get used to the form much spam takes after a while - though your exposure & therefore familiarity with it may depend on what time of day you normally visit. There are definitely 'hot' & 'cool' times in a day as to how much is posted. Often it lasts no more than a few minutes before being deleted, so if you're not there at that moment, you just won't see it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you should - Its definitely spam, and you *should* flag it.

Well, if I hadn't deleted the user anyway.